# Redirecting Request to Common Page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect

If the user tries to access an invalid page (which doesn't **exist**) how can I redirect request to a common page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following in `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>
            404
        </error-code>
        <location>
            /yourCommonPageForPageDoesntExist.html
        </location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to request the container to take care of `404` errors by configuring the `<error-page>` element in the `web.xml` like

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```